# UIAppearance via json file

Tags: ios, swift, uiappearance

I want to be able to style my iOS Swift-based app via config from a json file rather than manually writing UIAppearance logic in code. To do so, however, I effectively need to resolve class/function name from the strings in the JSON file. But Swift doesn't seem to allow for such mechanism, or at least it's not obvious, because if I understand `Selectors` correctly, they seem to be doing that already:

```
closeBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(
    barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.Stop,
    target: self,
    action: Selector("closeBarButtonItemClicked:"))
```

I understand the reasoning behind disallowing such pattern since it's typically unsafe, but in my case I feel that hardcoding hundreds of possible UIElement types and all their corresponding methods into the code/table would actually be a worse pattern - especially for a framework package which may be used in a project built against different version of Xcode with new or missing UIElement objects. I will have to define something along the lines of `"UIButton": UIButton.self` for every possible UI class and then `"setBackgroundColor": func (...) { UIObject.appearance().setBackgroundColor(...) }` for each method of each class, which imo is a pretty poor design pattern.

To make this cleaner, I'd want something along the lines of a string-eval for class and function names. I understand Swift doesn't allow this for safety reasons, but I'm wondering if there is a workaround. In this case I'm pretty certain I can prevent crashes/errors with a proper `try/catch` block, something along the lines of:

```
do {
    try callMethodOf(className, method: methodName, args: argList)
} catch {
    let alert = UIAlertView()
    alert.message = "\(className).\(methodName) entry defines an invalid style or is not stylable"
}
```

Comment: You might be able to get it working in Swift using a combination of `NSClassFromString`, `unsafeBitCast`, `class_getMethodImplementation`, etc. But the simplest solution may be to write the unsafe dynamic code in Objective-C and then call it from your Swift code.

Comment: Hey Alexander, did you find a feasible solution?

Comment: I ended up using a 3rd party library emulating stylesheets (it was written in Obj-C, hence bypassing the above limitation). Off the top of my head, unfortunately, I don't remember what the library name is, and it has been abandoned by project maintainer since then. However, there are a number of other libraries still in use with the same concept such as NUI, UISS, and InterfaCSS (a newcomer that wasn't around at the time but would probably be my top pick if I had to do this again today).